# Varying frequency by percentage, rather than with linear resistance?

Tags: capacitor, resistors, audio, frequency, 555

I'm using a 555 timer to generate musical tones, and employing resistors to get various pitches.  Instead of resistance by linear amounts (ie. 1KOhm) , is there a way to apply resistance by percentage?  For example, is there a type of resistor or other component which will reduce the flow to 50% ?  I ask this, because I would like to press one button to output half the frequency (an octave lower, musically) of the present frequency.  Alternatively, can this be done with capacitors? Thoughts?

Comment: Have you considered using a CD4060 clk/binary counter?  it has more octaves than an 88 key piano.  Then use one for each note. and a mux .. or dare I say a uC synth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a partial complete circuit of a 555 timer. When SW1 is open, the frequency will be:
$$\left( \frac{1.44}{(R1+2R2)C1} \right)$$

When the SW1 is close, the capacitance in effect will be C1 + C2 = 2uF. Doing so will reduce the frequency by half.
$$\left( \frac{1.44}{(R1+2R2)(C1+C2)} \right)$$

If doubling the frequency is needed, open SW2 to reduce the capacitance by half. The calculation for capacitance is:
$$\left( \frac{1}{\frac{1}{C1}+\frac{1}{C3}} \right)$$

---

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkV5DD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much!  This answered my question just as well as the one below.  I wish I could give you both a checkmark... not sure if it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you shunt the capacitor in the 555 astable circuit with another of equal value you will halve the frequency.

It will be halved regardless of what resistor values you use (at least to a first approximation, there might be some difference for very large or very small resistance values).

Comment: Thank you so much!  This answered my question just as well as the one above.  I wish I could give you both a checkmark... not sure if it's possible.

Comment: It's not. You should select the one answer which best answered your question (presumably Jason's). Sometimes it's better to wait a few hours to 24 hours in case a better answer comes along. You can, however, upvote as many useful answers as you like.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to regulate a 555 timer is using PWM duty cycle to switch the series R with a CMOS switch.

***[Here](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%202%208.55e-8%2014.841315910257661%2061%205%2050%0Aa%20304%20368%20432%20368%200%205%200%201000000%202.414448069692531%202.3809522214483416%0Aw%20304%20352%20304%20304%200%0Ar%20304%20304%20384%20304%200%2010000%0Aw%20432%20304%20432%20368%200%0Aw%20432%20368%20432%20432%200%0Ar%20432%20432%20304%20432%200%20100000%0Aw%20304%20384%20304%20432%200%0Ar%20304%20432%20208%20432%200%2010000%0Ag%20208%20432%20208%20464%200%0Ac%20304%20304%20208%20304%200%204.7000000000000004e-8%202.414448069692531%0Ag%20208%20304%20208%20336%200%0A211%20432%20368%20512%20368%200%201%208000%201%0A159%20432%20304%20384%20304%200%2020%2010000000000%0AR%20408%20288%20408%20256%201%202%2020000%202.5%202.5%200%200.25%0AR%20208%20384%20168%20384%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Ar%20304%20384%20208%20384%200%2010000%0Ao%209%2032%200%2012546%202.6192992730934628%200.0001%200%202%209%203%0Ao%2011%2032%200%204362%2010%200.00009765625%200%201%0Ao%2013%2032%200%204098%205%200.00009765625%200%202%2013%203%0A)*** shown using rail to rail CMOS OP Amp as the Schmitt trigger with 5% hysteresis ( you can use more for lower f up to 30% or so. )

The Clock is 5V 25% duty cycle and is   linear to f out here at 2.43kHz.  So cutting duty cycle by 50% reduces f by 50% exactly. (Within tolerances)

[image]